# Share I2C pins with other device when lacking GPIOs

Tags: esp8266, i2c, pins, communication

We're Using [`ESP12E`](https://potentiallabs.com/cart/image/cache/catalog/ESP8266/ESP12E_Pinouts-800x800.jpg) as our `MCU` and we have three functionality :

- `SIM800` connected to TX(GPIO1), RX(GPIO3)
- `Matrix Keypad` connected to `GPIOs: 14,13,2,10,0,4,5,16`
- `GLCD` connected to `GPIOs: 15,12`

And we also need to communicate with an `RTC(DS3231)` module via `I2C` bus!

So i'm wonder how we could do this?

Is it possible to share `I2C` pins with any other pins ?

And BTW for some reason we can't use IO expander such as `PCF8574`

Comment: *Why* can't you use a IO expander? It'll save you those 8 pins needed for the matrix keypad. Can you use any other external IC?

Comment: Yeah i know, that's a great `IC` but for now we've some restriction on PCB and some other issue on supply

Comment: GLCD (graphical LCD) connected via two wires? How is that possible, it usually requires far more wires? If this is already an I2C bus device, just put the RTC module on the exact same lines? I2C is a **bus** after all..

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt  It's a `ST7920` GLCD with 3 Wire software SPI using this nice lib:https://github.com/olikraus/u8g2 , also we're in serial mode so `cs` is chip enable and is connected to logic 1

Comment: Then if you used another display with same characteriscs (columns, lines, ..) but with a I2C interface, wouldn't your problems be solved? Then you have still 2 wires but with 2 devices on the I2C bus. Or throw in an I2C to SPI converter chip like NXP SC18IS602B.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already want to use I2C it makes sense to move other things onto that same I2C bus to save IO pins.  And even off-load processing.

For instance, you could move your keypad to a dedicated matrix keypad interface chip, such as the MAX7365 (probably overkill for a small keypad), or a general I2C GPIO IO expander, such as the MCP23017.

Answer (score 0):

We found `74C922` at long last! without any other choices.

A cheap, available, reliable and easy setup `IC`.

The simple schematic we use:

[image]

[here](http://www.instructables.com/id/16-key-Keypad-Decoding-with-an-AVR-MCU/) is a good topic to start with